# ios storage issue in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, download, local-storage

when i update

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>.
```

this request in my Info.plist it automatically create some folder which display some information regarding the app which i don’t  want to display [image: Image1] it shows myApp folder which is fine under this[image: Image2]
i want only Download folder as i am creating it, rest are unwanted folder which i don’t  want to create and it is being created automatically .
Also under Firebase many series folder is being created
So how can i stop to make such files in my app
Thanks